# How to download graphs from tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have trained a model and checking its log in tensorboard.
It shows a few graphs and gives me the option to download CSV or JSON, but I want the exact graph that they show on their portal.
Here is how it looks:
[image: Accuracy graph]

Is there any way to download it in PNG or SVG format?

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3368) issue it is not on the todo-list of the tensorflow team. But there's a suggestion for a possible workaround.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Click the checkbox "Show data download links" at the top left. This will add a download icon below the chart to download the chart in SVG format [image: tensorboard]

Comment: Why isn't it activated by default tho? XD

Answer (score -1):

You can use tensorboardX and import SummaryWriter to write scalars.
Try to open the tensorboard server in google chrome (make sure you checked the Show data links) and you will have an option to download the current graph as svg file.